# How to get sum all elements inside array

Tags: mongodb, sum, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Okay, so I have a collection of objects that look like this:

```
{  
 "address":{  
  "building":"1007",
  "coord":[  
     -73.856077,
     40.848447
  ],
  "street":"Morris Park Ave",
  "zipcode":"10462"
},
"borough":"Bronx",
"cuisine":"Bakery",
"grades":[  
  {  
     "date":{  
        "$date":1393804800000
     },
     "grade":"A",
     "score":2
  },
  {  
     "date":{  
        "$date":1378857600000
     },
     "grade":"A",
     "score":6
  },
  {  
     "date":{  
        "$date":1358985600000
     },
     "grade":"A",
     "score":10
  },
  {  
     "date":{  
        "$date":1322006400000
     },
     "grade":"A",
     "score":9
  },
  {  
     "date":{  
        "$date":1299715200000
     },
     "grade":"B",
     "score":14
  }
],
"name":"Morris Park Bake Shop",
"restaurant_id":"30075445"
}
```

This is just one element from a collection of these. How do I write a MongoDB query so that I get restaurants that have a sum of scores greater than `70` for example?

I'm new to MongoDB, sorry if the question is repeated but I didn't manage to find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to calculate the sum on your array and put that inside of [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gte: [ 
                    { $reduce: { input: "$grades", initialValue: 0, in: { $add: [ "$$value", "$$this.score" ] } } }, 
                    70 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: `$$this.grade`  should be `$$this.score`?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$gte": [ 
        { "$sum": "$grades.score" }, 
        70
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

or using find query

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [ 
      { "$sum": "$grades.score" },
      70
    ]
  }
})
```